# Track Voting Up and Down, Improving Curation, Feedback and reducing workload

Tags: discussion

**Edit** Should 5 standard user down votes automatically trigger a 72hr removal warning on poor quality posts?

Linking down votes (**and up votes**)to knowledge base FAQ's would provide a clear and consistent feedback mechanism to the poster and reduces or removes any need to comment to clarify largely. This provides a win/win for improving clarity and consistency and reducing work/effort required by community members viewing bad or poor questions.

If un-actioned or more than 5 down votes received a deletion trigger is engaged and removes post within 72hrs.

This improves curation, searching SO, tracks voting both up and down.

So lets curate harder and clearer act to remove quickly with clear feedback on what to change or  its  gone. Not a low quality post with down votes left behind that helps no one as far as I can see.

**NB** Historically personally, I don't care particularly about upvotes, maybe that's wrong because I usually assign upvotes for helpfulness of poster or attempt to help whether correct or not maybe that is wrong?

I humbly await your constructive comments below.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make sense of what you're asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Do you have anything in mind? Note that the *sheer volume of new questions* plays a huge factor in all this; any solution *has to scale*. Stack Overflow is not a small website with a few questions per day, and new users are given a *ton* of help if they would only first read that help. As such, by the time new users post a question, we expect them to have done their homework first and if they haven't then they are wasting our time (e.g. are being rude to *us answerers*).

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for the comment. I proposed a solution previously but it caused confusion over whether people felt there was/wasn't a need for improvement or that they did not like my idea for improvement. I will update  the question.

Comment: @sayth, re: your edit, I did leave a comment saying I did not understand what you were asking and requesting clarifications. Unfortunately, the bold paragraph you have added does not help me understand your point better at all.

Comment: And take into account that downvotes are not necessarily communicating anything to *you*, but are also used to communicate to the *rest of the community* about wether a post here is worth anyone's time or is worth discussing or if we agree with the premise.

Comment: But isn't that up to the reader whether the post has value? I thought  that  we were aiming to assist the  poster not potentially stop someone reading a post they may or may not like.

Comment: Removing bad questions is a *necessary and important* part of curating questions and answers to create a great resource. A lot of people try hard to improve the questions that can be salvaged, but the simple truth is that there are still a lot of questions that can't be helped.

Comment: Here's a simple solution that is "fair, equitable and provides a mechanism to allow contributors to improve": Severely raise the quality standards expected of posters as well as the punishment for not meeting them. E.g. suspend people for bad posts like random typo or "please do my work" questions, non-answers posted as answers, chameleon questions, etc. It's fair and equitable as long as it's the same for everyone, and gives motivation to improve - if bad users don't improve they can't ask questions. It would even lower mod workload due to many more banned users and thus less questions...

Comment: No, our main goal is not to assist the poster. It is to create a repository of questions and answers that are helpful to the larger programming community. If someone asks a question that no one else can understand, we're not obligated to expend effort trying to help them.

Comment: @BilltheLizard true and I agree whole heartedly with curation. But like it or not people can take down votes negatively. If the  question was basicallly  good but a bit unclear or  worded in some way confusing a down vote doesn't assist the poster or subsequent user. If we could tag  a  down vote potentially  might add simple  feedback that could help.

Comment: Downvotes are already "tagged" with simple feedback. Hover your mouse over the downvote button.

Comment: @BilltheLizard thanks never knew that existed. Also a strong repository of questions and answers will thrive in a strong community. Ignoring the community for answers I wouldn't see as productive.

Comment: I  may have to accept  that  where I want improvement or see an opportunity for  improvement others at the moment don't, or I haven't expressed in a way that gets their  understanding and call to action. This could cause me to receive a lot of down votes  but at least when I get it right  SO will be improved for the better from my efforts

Comment: We have a strong community, and I think you're the one ignoring us. We (the community) don't *want* to waste time on unsalvagable questions, so we don't. There are plenty of questions in the mediocre-to-great range to spend our time on.

Comment: @BilltheLizard as my comment above (we posted at the same time). My only goal is to  help.

Comment: Oh but there are plenty of down votes on good questions as well. Personally don't see the value in that, though quality is perception based.

Comment: @sayth You might think the question is good.  Clearly whomever downvoted disagrees.  Questions quality is of course subjective.  I'm sure that downvoter is wondering why you're upvoting a bad question.

Comment: @Servy I'll say it again; we should *demand* explanations for up-votes...

Comment: @BilltheLizard   can I ask why we don't have vote to remove not just vote to close. Wouldn't that achieve better curtain?  Remove bad posts and reduce duplicate posts allowing new posters to search and find better results without wading through poor posts.

Comment: @sayth You can vote to delete. That privilege is unlocked at 10,000 reputation. A question has to be closed first before it can be deleted. That way the author of the post has the option to improve it before it gets deleted.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I up-voted your comment, so here is the explanation - I like the unitato picture.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I up voted your comment because you up voted mine.

Comment: Conclusion: Detection of voting rings will become easier if you start demanding explanations for upvotes.

Comment: Ok so I respect the community wishes for curation and then would expect this post to be deleted to improve  the search results.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi    Can you review my question updated and see if that provides more clarity based on comments  and feedback please?

Comment: @sayth, well, it does clarify things a little. *Should 5 standard user down votes automatically trigger a 72hr removal warning on poor quality posts?* seems related to our new-ish policy about questions being a scarce resource, which goes in the right direction IMHO. And yes, five downvotes on one of your first questions *should* let you sit back for a while (and take that time to reconsider how to use the site).

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion  I am more than happy for explanations for up votes as well as down votes. It has merit though you may have intended it sarcastically. I am just proposing imporved feedback and curation mechanisms. They needn't be commplex and should reduce workload and effort. Eg linking downvotes to knowledge base FAQ's gives clear consistent feedback to the poster and reduces the need to comment to clarify win/win no? If unactioned post deleted, improves curation, no?

Comment: This is where the difference lies. You think we should give clear consistent feedback to the poster, but the whole idea is that we are not doing anything for "the poster". We are building a library, everybody contributes whatever they can. Some contributes questions, some contributes answers, some contribute in moderation and cleaning up. We are NOT doing it for the poster, we are doing it for future users. If the poster gets benefited, it's a side effect. The members can cast delete votes if something needs removal.

Comment: There is a script too, which automatically removes posts which are abandoned or have no significant value(based on certain criteria). The reason we don't delete the rest of the old unactioned posts that you see on the site is because it has some value. Unanswered doesn't mean useless. The question is a contribution. Someday, someone who knows the answer might come and answer it. Please try to understand the fundamental concept that this is a library building activity, not a free debugging service, or a free code writing service.

Comment: Think of it as a Wikipedia of all programming questions and answers. If anyone Googles a question, hopefully they will find the answer here. If they don't find it here, they can contribute the question here for future users, so that someday someone might answer it and benefit future users.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since I'm bored and want to procrastinate I wrote you a not so handy step-by-step guide on how to be more respectful and assistive. Be warned, I turned your question into a different direction...

1. Remember that *Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.*
   It's not a forum, it's not a free version of guru.com, it's not a support hotline. And it might sound harsh, but we are not a training center, we can't really teach you how to become a professional programmer. But we can help you to get there. But we need your help. So let's continue...
2. Analyze the problem. Try to think like a professional or enthusiast programmer

   - break the problem down into smaller units
   - debug the problem, inspect variables, step through code, comment out code, experiment with your problem. Does it still exist if you do x, y or z? Write those attempts down.
   - if something stopped working and you think you didn't change anything, look at the diff in your version control system (yes, even if you don't work on a team you should use one, commit often)
   - comment out as much code as possible so you have an example that shows the problem with the smallest amount of code possible
   - do this for a prolonged amount of time. if you spent less than 15 minutes to figure out a solution yourself there is a good chance that you are unable to write a good question
3. Research the problem with the help of Google and Stack Overflow

   - even if you won't find a solution that exactly fits your problem, think about the stuff that you've just read. Can it be applied to your situation? Learn to become an analytic person.

Depending on your problem it might be better to do step 3 before step 2. If your problem produces any output (e.g. error message, an exception) put as much of it into Google.

Still no solution? Time to ask a question on Stack Overflow

4. If you haven't done already, take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking your question
5. So it's finally time to write down your question.

   - Think about a good subject. It should be clear and should tell the reader what your question is about. "My code does not work" is not a good subject. Can't think of a good one? Leave it empty for now and come back when you are done writing the body
   - Describe the problem
   - Tell us what you expect and what did not work. Did you try different solutions? Tell us about them ("I tried different things") is not good enough
   - if there are any error messages, copy and paste these message into the question. If your problem is a crash or an exception that comes with a stack trace, post that as well. Don't use screenshots for these, there is usually a way to get them as plain text from your IDE.
   - post your code, in writing. Don't use screenshots. We want to copy and paste it to play with your code

     - it should compile with minimum work. If you use a bazillion variables in your code it's nice if you mock them for us so we just have to copy and paste. But mention if you do this
     - use proper formatting
     - omit method stubs that don't do anything
     - Remove unnecessary whitespace
     - remove unnecessary comments that come from the IDE template
     - You can use inline comments to show us where problems have occurred. But please use the proper comment syntax for that language (e.g. prefix them with `//`). Remember we want to copy and paste to try your code
   - now is the time to tell us about some of the variables. What values do they have? If your JSON decoder does not work show us the JSON source. You can remove confidential parts. But the values (and the code) you post here should actually reproduce the problem. We don't like to spent time on a question that is unsolvable because the redacted code works. Double check if the problem still exist with the version you post here. Basically you should really try to make it easy for people to reproduce the problem.
   - If you think your code is correct but it behaves weird it might be a good idea to mention the compiler (or the IDE if you don't know the compiler version) and the operating system you are using. Maybe your problem is related to one of these.
   - Think about good tags for your question. There is no need to use all five tags. If your question is code that does not compile it's usually okay to just tag the question with the language. No need to sweat it, it's easy to use to fix tags. But we want to avoid it, so help us.
   - Don't hit submit yet.
6. Reread the preview of your question. Does it look okay? Is the code formatted correctly? Is there anything missing? For bonus points get a glass of water and reread it again.
7. Hit submit. And wait.

---

I know it's an elitist approach. I know nobody wants to spend so much time and effort. I know that's a lot to ask for. Especially if you are a beginner.
But that's not a problem, these steps are not the law, it's just what I do nearly every single day. If I have a problem (which happens quite a lot) I turn to Stack Overflow for help. But I don't start with asking a question. Stack Overflow already has answers to most of the questions that are asked these days. That's great, but you have to find them.

Enough bragging about how awesome I am. I think even beginners should be able to follow these steps. If you can't perform a step, skip it and continue with the next one. Once you've asked your question go back to the steps you skipped and see if you can do something to perform them the next time.
All of these steps are huge timesavers. If you know how to solve a problem yourself you don't have to wait for Stack Overflow to answer your question.

And I know I put the main burden on the men and women who ask questions, but that's my point. If you make life easier for people that answer questions, you will get less downvotes, less harsh comments, and more important faster and better answers.

We like to answer questions, we like to help, that's why we are here. The problem is these days there are so many question. Especially in high traffic tags too many not-so-bad questions stay without answers because we can't find these questions. They are just hidden between bad, easy to answer and already answered questions that are blocking our view.

Comment: I scrolled down on my mobile to see the author's name. I wanted to know who was bored enough to answer this amazing question :)

Answer (score 11):

I've said it before, but I'll repeat.

I'm happy giving my skills, experience and time to answering good questions, at no charge.  After all, I learn plenty from the existing SO answers, so it seems fair enough.

I'm grudgingly willing to spend time on a quick read and one downvote/closevote click at no charge on bad questions.

If I'm 'forced' to spend time on explaining downvotes, I insist on getting paid for it.   I view it as a waste of my time that could otherwise be spent on answering good questions but, if I get, say, 0.5€ per downvote-explanation, I'm fine with that.  PayPal will do nicely, thank you.

Comment: This ^^ The purpose of rating the relative value of things is to make it easier for those willing to donate their time to find stuff worthy of spending that time on. Make it *harder* to contribute to that rating system, and it becomes harder to do.

Comment: @Martin James    I would assert that down voting doesn't achieve what you really want. The removal of poor questions that clog SO.

Comment: @sayth Nowhere does Martin say anything about "removal of poor questions". Voting is a rough, comparative indicator of the community's perception of quality. Potential Answerers - and the original Asker - can use that rating to guide them, if they so choose.

Comment: @AndrewBarber  tying down votes to deletion would be beneficial  and allow  caring users to trigger a vote for removal  request and keep the  site cleaner, more reference-able and searchable. Would  mean less workload and more time to assist those attempting to ask good questions get there overcoming language or knowledge barriers. Directly  link down votes  to knowledge base articles that would improve the question, that stops Martin having to re write the same thing, provides feedback that can be used and if not acted deletes the post in 72hrs keeping the site  cleaner. No?.

Comment: @sayth There is already a way that downvotes on questions can trigger deletion. It's a script that runs to clean up old, unanswered, downvoted (and I believe closed) questions. So there's that. No it's not fast, but, having had a (rather terrible) question deleted to that, it does work. (I realize this isn't quite what you're looking for, but it does exist.)

Comment: @Kendra         thanks. It is good to know, I just started a question not as a solution but to get a discussion to what appears to be a problem. As blackbolt noted in another discussion there a lot of proposals to "alter/fix" down voting its actions and perceptions. It may not be broken but there appears to be a part of the community feeling that in its current form it is, hence the re-oocurrence of similar topic questions and varied proposed solutions.

Comment: @MartinJames    I have updated and edited my propoosal perhaps now it adds more value to you and would reduce the need to comment down votes but would provide the poster a clearer feedback mechanism and path to resolution.